# Why does this button image flash the first time the image is changed?

Tags: flutter

I have a button in my Flutter app that has a DecorationImage that I want to change in onTap, onTapCancel and onTapUp (when button is pressed vs. not pressed). Everything works just fine except for a very quick flash where the image seems to disappear when the image is changed for the first time. After that it works seamlessly.

At first I thought this was due to the image not being loaded to memory or something so I tried initializing the image variables in initState but that did nothing.

```
class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {

static AssetImage buttonUnselected;
static AssetImage buttonSelected;

AssetImage button;

@override
void initState() {
  buttonUnselected = new AssetImage(‘assets/label.png’);
  buttonSelected = new AssetImage(‘assets/label_selected.png’);

  button = buttonUnselected;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: UIWidgets.getAppBar(),
    body: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage(“assets/background_main.jpg”),
                fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,),
            ),
          ),
          new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
              child: new Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new GestureDetector(
                        onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) => this.setState(() {
                          button = buttonSelected;
                        }),
                        onTapCancel: () => this.setState(() {
                          button = buttonUnselected;
                        }),
                        onTapUp: (TapUpDetails details) => this.setState(() {
                          button = buttonUnselected;
                        }),
                        child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
                            child: Center(child: Text(“Button”)),
                            height: 100,
                            width: 400,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: button
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                  ]
              )
          )
        ]
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the image is *actually* downloaded to browser cache? Use network panel and observe if initialization downloads image.

Comment: @PeterM it's an asset file on disk, not a downloaded file.

Comment: It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you don't have super() in initState(). It worked fine for me.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
```